# RDLC re-initializes static data in assembly

Tags: asp.net, static, .net-assembly, rdlc

I have an ASP.NET app with RDLC reports. The magic happens in a separate assembly that I reference in the main ASP app. I have some static data in this assembly, which I want to reference in my objects after they have been serialized and de-serialized by the RDLC report system.

What I have found is the static fields are re-initialized during the RDLC report run, perhaps RDLC is loading up a new copy of the assembly. Thus my objects are hitting null refs on the static data, where I am expecting the data previously set.

What's going on here? Is there a way to ensure only one copy of an assembly gets loaded?

Answer (score 1):

The reason seems to be that the RDLC ReportViewer operates within a separate AppDomain, and thus does not share memory with the main app.

I spent several hours refactoring my DB classes so they could be serialized and then de-serialized, all for the benefit of RDLC, only to find that after de-serializing they were not able to assign the correct DB provider because that was sitting in a static class that RDLC cannot see because it is runs in a different AppDomain.

This is the first I've really heard about AppDomains so I was not able to search for these related questions that shed light on the problem:

- [Does ReportViewer run in a separate AppDomain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665915/does-reportviewer-run-in-a-separate-appdomain)
- [.NET LocalReport / .rdlc AppDomain issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763930/net-localreport-rdlc-appdomain-issues)
- [What happens to the static data in a class if it is accessed across app domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957868/what-happens-to-the-static-data-in-a-class-if-it-is-accessed-across-app-domains)
- [Sharing data between AppDomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206961/sharing-data-between-appdomains)

I found tips on forcing the report to run in the current AppDomain, which is obsolete and requires enabling CAS, but I could not get this to work in my project (I only tried for a short while):

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.executereportincurrentappdomain.aspx
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security-policy-compatibility-and-migration

Finally, I have decided that the correct solution is not to do code gymnastics to trick ReportViewer to work with my data - but rather to provide the report with a simple POCO that serializes and de-serializes easily, and has no complicated dependencies.

This is a good reason why DB objects should be simple and easily serializable, and the business logic should be in a separate object/wrapper on top of the DB object. These complicated "God objects" of mine have been bugging me for a while now!